# highlight navigation dropdown

Tags: jquery, navigation

I want my dropdown link to highlight, but also the link in the top of that dropdown. If you have a look at http://rezolve.4pixels.com/banks-and-telcos/home/banks-and-telcos.php and you click the last link in any of the dropdowns they work perfectly (they highlight their own 'li' and the parent 'li'). I just can't work out why only the last link in each dropdown does what I want ie none of the others apart from the last. I'd have thought 'parents' would pick up all ancestor 'li'

My script is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
  var currentPageUrl = location.href;
  $('.nk-nav li a').each(function(){
      $(this).parents("li").toggleClass('active', this.href === currentPageUrl);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it "partially" works...
I don't think it is because of your script.

You'll notice that `console.log(currentPageUrl);` returns the full address.
*(including http://rezolve.4pixels.com)*.

Your script compares this to the relative URL.
*(without http://rezolve.4pixels.com)*

**So it can't be matching really often.**

So here is a script I suggest you to try...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  "use strict";

  var currentPageUrl = location.href;
  console.log(currentPageUrl);

  $('.nk-drop-item').find('a').each(function(){
    if( "http://rezolve.4pixels.com"+ $(this).attr("href") === currentPageUrl ){
      $(this).closest(".nk-drop-item").addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

But I don't know if there will be interference with what is actually highlighting...

Comment: Thank you Louys, I can see now how it was comparing the two addresses wasn't giving me a positive everytime. It's highlighting my top nav now which is the most important thing.